# I want to generate BKS file to configure android for https communication

Tags: android, ssl, wso2

I want to generate BKS file to configure android device for https communication. For that I am following [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS320/Configuring+Android+for+HTTPS+Communication#ConfiguringAndroidforHTTPSCommunication-Step2:GeneratingaBKSfile)

When I am running this command

```
 keytool -noprompt -import -v -trustcacerts -alias godaddy -file cert.crt -keystore truststore.bks -storetype BKS -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider -providerpath bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar -storepass 'wso2carbon'
```

It gives me..

> keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: cert.crt (The system
>   cannot find the file specified)

What is **"cert.crt"** file in this? from where i can get this file and  what is the alternative for **"cert.crt"** file??

Comment: Thanks for edit..

Comment: can anyone give me solution?